# $\left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+5\ge5\left(\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2$

Tags: inequality

For all non- negative real numbers such that: $a+b+c=5$ then: $$\left(\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}-\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+5\ge5\left(\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2(*)$$[AOPS link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2758771p24986054)

I can not find a good solution for the problem. Here is SOS form I used software:
$$(*)\iff \sum_{cyc}{\frac{a(b+c)\left(b+c-a-2\sqrt{bc}\right)^2}{5\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}+(b+c-a)\sqrt{bc}+2a(b+c)}}\ge0$$
Also: $5\ge \sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$ and $ ab+bc+ca\le \dfrac{5}{\sqrt{3}}$

But how to use the relativé
Is there any simpler way ig: AM-GM, CS,.. to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I am fairly certain that $ab+bc+ca\le \dfrac{5}{\sqrt{3}}$ is wrong, just taking $a=b=c$ yields a much larger number. With Lagrange multipliers, it is easy to verify that the max is 25/3

Comment: Yes, I see. But how to complete the rest?

Comment: anyone help me?

Comment: I have tried this a couple of times now, but I could not figure something out that does not require calculus. Perhaps you could pick up where I left off, applying Jensen's Inequality to $5(\sqrt{x}-3/2)^2$ yields something more manageable.

Comment: It seems hard. I spent a lot of time without success

Comment: I try a lot but the inequality is very complicated